# Table view with UIBlurEffect become laggy

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

i have problem with tableview, after implementing top bar with uiblurview tableview is laggy on iphone5 scrolling tableview takes 20-25% cpu, before adding blur view. Worked perfectly.
looking forward for any performance help

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%li%i",(long)indexPath.row,cellvar]];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%li%i",(long)indexPath.row,cellvar]];

        if ([self.obrazki count]>0) {
            CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake((cell.frame.size.width/tableViewOffset)-(tableView.frame.size.width*0.92/2), 10, tableView.frame.size.width*0.92, tableView.frame.size.width*0.92);
            UIImageView * image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
            image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            image.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
            [image setImage:[self.obrazki objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            image.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [cell addSubview:image];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            UIVisualEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
            UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView= [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
            visualEffectView.frame = CGRectMake((cell.frame.size.width/tableViewOffset)-(tableView.frame.size.width*0.92/2)-0.5, 9,tableView.frame.size.width*0.92+1,35);
            CAShapeLayer * maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
            maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: visualEffectView.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){25.0, 25.0}].CGPath;

            visualEffectView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
            visualEffectView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            [cell addSubview:visualEffectView];

            UILabel *likeCount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((cell.frame.size.width/tableViewOffset)-(tableView.frame.size.width*0.92/2)+distanceFromStart, 4,tableView.frame.size.width*0.92,35)];
            likeCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imagesLikes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            likeCount.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            likeCount.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            likeCount.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin" size:20];
            [visualEffectView addSubview:likeCount];
            CGRect imageLikeFrame = CGRectMake(likeCount.frame.origin.x-20, likeCount.frame.origin.y+7.5, 16, 16);
            UIImageView * imageLike = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageLikeFrame];
            [imageLike setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like.png"]];
            imageLike.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
            imageLike.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [visualEffectView addSubview:imageLike];
            NSLog(@"Generating:%i",indexPath.row);
        }
    }
  //  NSLog(@"LoadingOnView:%i",indexPath.row);
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a cell (an instance of UITableViewCell) for each row and not reusing dequeued cells. "dequeueReusableCell..." is there for performance reasons. Use it to dequeue and reuse other row's cell.

Use a constant cell identifier for all the cells and just modify the cell for each row. That is, change images or texts. But reuse the cells if you want any performance improvement. That is the first thing to do. Then, tell us if the performance is enough or if you need even more optimizations.

Comment: unfortunately didnt helped, maybe little bit better. i forgot to say that this tableview has maximum 10 elements. content is image 640x640 but without blurview worked perfectly.

Comment: Let's assume, it's enough.There was problem because of custom cell. Now it's better but it's not the best, maybe iphone5 is old for this. Thanks.